# How will you customise a html page so that it accepts multiple language?

Tags: html, html-parsing

How will you  customise a html page so that it accepts multiple language?

Answer (score 2):

I will cite W3 [Internationalization Quick Tips for the Web](http://www.w3.org/International/quicktips/) :

- Encoding. Use Unicode wherever possible for content, databases, etc. Always declare the encoding of content.
- Escapes. Use characters rather than escapes (e.g. `&#xE1;` `&#225;` or `&aacute;`) whenever you can.
- Language. Declare the language of documents and indicate internal language changes.
- Presentation vs. content. Use style sheets for presentational information. Restrict markup to semantics.
- Images, animations & examples. Check for translatability and inappropriate cultural bias.
- Forms. Use an appropriate encoding on both form and server. Support local formats of names/addresses, times/dates, etc.
- Text authoring. Use simple, concise text. Use care when composing sentences from multiple strings.
- Navigation. On each page include clearly visible navigation to localized pages or sites, using the target language.
- Right-to-left text. For XHTML, add dir="rtl" to the html tag. Only re-use it to change the base direction.
- Check your work. Validate!  Use techniques, tutorials, and articles at http://www.w3.org/International/

For more information follow W3 recommendations : http://www.w3.org/International/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a decent server-side web technology, there are many to choose from, which contains support for internationalization. Essentially it comes down to specifying the different pieces of text that the site needs to display, assigning a label to each message, creating different versions of each label in separate language files, and using the server-side code, reference the label name and a country code to display the text in the appropriate language.

The first step is to determine your requirements, your hosting environment and then figure out what options are available to you. If you can provide some more information we might be able to steer you in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I make a bunch of assumptions about what you are trying to achieve:

**Serve the document as UTF-8**

Browsers will tend to then return a UTF-8 response to the server when any forms are submitted (forms being the only way that a page is going to "accept" anything), and UTF-8 can handle the characters used in just about every language.